# Feature request: Automatcially detect non-tags

Tags: feature-request, markdown

When I write a sentence that talks about, say, List<string> or vector<int>, it turns into "List or vector" in the preview (and I believe also when it is posted).

StackOverflow should detect these non-HTML tags and make replacements like "<" to "&lt;" automatically.

How to distinguish them from real HTML tags:

1. They aren't valid HTML tags
2. There is no matching </string> and </int>

Answer (score 5):

No. You should mark-up code as code using backticks. For example, write:

```
`List<string>`
```

in the body of the paragraph instead of

> List<string>

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I still think it would be a good idea if StackOverflow detected cases of non-HTML and replaced "<T>" with "`<T>`" as necessary.

Comment: That would require trying to parse the whole textbox rather than one well defined chunk at a time (which is a big advantage of Markdown) and it would be very hard to get it right.

Comment: You could just use the tags themselves for local parsing (doesn't SO only accept a specific set of HTML tags? Just check to see if "T" or "int" is in the set of accepted tags.)